# Where did my dropped item go?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

I just pickpocketed an Orcish bow off of someone (much better than my current bow), but while I was dropping items from my inventory to clear some weight, I accidentally dropped the bow. Now I can only see the two items I dropped first on the ground.

Where did my bow go, and can I get it back without reloading a saved game?

Comment: Perhaps it slid down a slope, or you confidently kicked it away?

Comment: @Arkive I don't think so, as I dropped about 10 things, and only 2 are visible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some items don't drop right on the ground below you but at some distance away, possible of a ledge.

I have seen one of my items at a considerable distance, as if I would have thrown it away.

If you don't see it in your perimeter, you could consider it a bug where the item fell out of the level...

Comment: It seems this way. I've looked high and low for a good 15 minutes, can't find it anywhere.